# Is it possible to change the pressure of a gas at constant volume without increasing the temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

$v_{rms}$ of an ideal gas is given by $\sqrt{\dfrac{3RT}{M}}$ .

Now I believe that this depends *only* on **temperature** and molar mass of the gas. But someone told me to write RT as $\dfrac{PV}{n}$, then the formula would show pressure dependency at constant volume. But I still believe that it shows *only* *direct temperature dependency* because pressure of an ideal gas at constant volume can only(?) be increased by increasing the temperature.

Now, I am just wondering if there's a method to increase the pressure of the gas without *us raising the temperature*. I mean that the pressure should increase and *then* the temperature should increase as a result of Gay-Lussac's pressure law (not the other way round).

I think then the claim that $v_{rms}$ depends on pressure will be valid.

Answer (score 2):

The only free variable would then be n, which you could raise: add more gas particles. To do this without raising T, you'd need the same $v_{rms}$.

Your wish to raise p without raising T, then have T increase seems contradictory, unless you allow for (exothermic) chemical reactions between different particle types, that kick in slowly.